# What are the performance characteristics of the getProgramAccounts() call? Is it scalable as the chain grows?

Tags: performance, rpc, getprogramaccounts, scalability

What is the algorithmic complexity of a `getProgramAccounts()` call?
Do the Solana nodes store all the accounts ever created?
Do the nodes have to scan the entire ledger? Are there any indexes in place?
Do the `length` or `memcmp` filters reduce the volume of data that needs to be scanned?
Is it distributed across multiple nodes or does only the RPC node handle the query?

As the size of the ledger increases, would it be increasingly slower to do a `getProgramAccounts()` call?

Comment: please restrict each post to one question. the lack of focus reduces quality

Comment: @trent.sol could you suggest which parts I shall remove?

Comment: everything with a question mark could theoretically be elaborated to its own post

Comment: Just want to add getProgramAccounts turned out to be a pretty heavy call.